# Pygame error : video system not initialized

Tags: python, pygame

```
import sys,pygame
pygame.init()

size = width , height = 600,400 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

tux = pygame.image.load("tux.png")

screen.blit(tux,(200,200))
screen.blit(tux,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()

while 1:
ev = pygame.event.poll() 
if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
```

The above code is showing this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    169             else:
    170                 filename = fname
--> 171             exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    172     else:
    173         def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\digi.abhshk\Desktop\tux.py in <module>()
    11 pygame.display.flip()
    12 while 1:
--->13         ev = pygame.event.poll()
    14         if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
    15             pygame.quit()

error: video system not initialized
```

I am very new to pygame , what is this error and how to remove it ? 
PS: tux is the png image i am using in this file

Comment: It is not the same , the answer there says use pygame.QUIT , instead of pygame.quit() and I am already using that !

Comment: What happens if there are multiple events occurring in one frame? What if I'm holding down `cmd` while I try to quit? It is better practice to use the tried and tested `for event in pygame.event.get():`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't break your while loop after calling `pygame.quit()`.

Just use

```
while 1:
    ev = pygame.event.poll() 
    if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
        break
pygame.quit()
```

or something like that. Otherwise, you'll call `pygame.event.poll()` *after* `pygame.quit()` on the next iteration of the loop, which will lead to your error.

Comment: Your answer delivered me from a lot of headache today. Thanks!